# opencv - Stitching more than 2 images

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I am now trying to align more than two images together in C++ with opencv. The problem is when I stitch more than 2, the previous image cannot be loaded.

For example, imageContainer now contains three images.

First Image:
[image: First image]

Second Image:
[image: Second Image]

Third Image:
[image: Third Image]

First iteration of the loop: (Combining the first and second image)
[image: First iteration]

Second iteration of the loop: (Combining the result from first iteration and third image)
[image: Second iteration]

You can see that after the second iteration, the result image does not contain the object. (Left side of the last image is all black),

In main.cpp

```
cv::Mat result = *imageContainer.begin();
for(vector<cv::Mat>::iterator itr = imageContainer.begin(); itr != imageContainer.end(); itr++){
    if(itr == imageContainer.begin())
        continue;
    result = applySURF(result, *itr);
}
```

In SURF.cpp

```
cv::Mat applySURF(cv::Mat object, cv::Mat image){

/* More codes here but it won't affect solving the problem */

    cv::Mat result;
    cv::warpPerspective(image, result, transformationMat, cv::Size(object.cols + image.cols, image.rows));

    cv::Mat half(result, cv::Rect(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows));
    object.copyTo(half);

    imshow("Object", object);
    imshow("Result", result);
    cvWaitKey(0);

    return result;
}
```

I guess the problem is related to Region Of Interest (ROI). How can I solve it?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Hello there, I am having sam problem. how did you solved it finally?

Comment: Hello, how can this problem be solved?? I am facing a similar issue. Need help.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:)

I tested some cases and got a conclusion that  if the size of target image is not same as the source image, it will reallocate a new Mat to be pasted. In your case the size of ROI is not same as *object*, it allocates a new Mat *half* and it is not related to *result* 
anymore. So your **copyTo** function copies the object into the *new Mat half* instead of the ROI of *result*.

```
cv::Mat applySURF(cv::Mat object, cv::Mat image){

/* More codes here but it won't affect solving the problem */

    cv::Mat result;
    cv::warpPerspective(image, result, transformationMat, cv::Size(object.cols + image.cols, image.rows));

    cv::Mat half(result, cv::Rect(0, 0, object.cols, object.rows));
    object.copyTo(half);

    cv::imshow("Object", object);
    cv::imshow("Result", result);
    cv::WaitKey(0);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I try your codes in my program. But still, the image's "region" in the result is all black. Thanks for your comment. I am still working around it.

Comment: I understand your ideas: the half should be a ROI of the same size as object so object can be successfully paste on to result.

Comment: Note that warping depends on the homography. Have you tried using the inverse of the calculated homography for the second case?